# synchronous execution of database (postgres) query using asyncio not working together with ormar ORM (fastapi app)

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, fastapi, ormar

I'm building an api using `fastapi` with `postgres` and `ormar` for ORM (currently using `docker-compose` to develop locally). Routes are working fine, but I'm having trouble adding JWT user authorization using the natively async `ormar` to confirm users in the db (I'm following [this example](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/) but looking to replace the `fake_db` with calls to the actual db in the `authenticate` function).

I've tried to use `asyncio` to convert the database call to a synchronous operation in order to execute it as part of `authenticate` but keep getting errors suggesting I'm not adding the task to the right thread or pool.

Here's the snippet causing the issue (specifically `asyncio.run` is where it happens)

```
import asyncio 
from app.db import User


def authenticate(email: str, password: str) -> Optional[User]:

    user = await User.objects.filter(email=email).first()
    asyncio.run(user)

    if not user:
        return None
    if not verify_password(password, user.hashed_password):
        return None
    return user
```

and here's the stack trace

```
web_1      | Future exception was never retrieved
web_1      | future: <Future finished exception=ConnectionDoesNotExistError('connection was closed in the middle of operation')>
web_1      | asyncpg.exceptions.ConnectionDoesNotExistError: connection was closed in the middle of operation
web_1      | INFO:     192.168.176.2:50038 - "POST /auth/login HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
web_1      | ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
web_1      | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 396, in run_asgi
web_1      |     result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__
web_1      |     return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 199, in __call__
web_1      |     await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 111, in __call__
web_1      |     await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
web_1      |     raise exc from None
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
web_1      |     await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
web_1      |     raise exc from None
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
web_1      |     await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 566, in __call__
web_1      |     await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 227, in handle
web_1      |     await self.app(scope, receive, send)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 41, in app
web_1      |     response = await func(request)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 201, in app
web_1      |     raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 150, in run_endpoint_function
web_1      |     return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/concurrency.py", line 34, in run_in_threadpool
web_1      |     return await loop.run_in_executor(None, func, *args)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
web_1      |     result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
web_1      |   File "/app/./app/api/routes/auth.py", line 19, in login
web_1      |     user = authenticate(email=form_data.username, password=form_data.password)
web_1      |   File "/app/./app/core/auth.py", line 35, in authenticate
web_1      |     asyncio.run(user)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
web_1      |     return loop.run_until_complete(main)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
web_1      |     return future.result()
web_1      |   File "/app/./app/core/auth.py", line 19, in get_user
web_1      |     return await User.objects.get(email=email) #User.objects.filter(email=email).first()
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ormar/queryset/queryset.py", line 929, in get
web_1      |     return await self.filter(*args, **kwargs).get()
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ormar/queryset/queryset.py", line 945, in get
web_1      |     rows = await self.database.fetch_all(expr)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/databases/core.py", line 142, in fetch_all
web_1      |     return await connection.fetch_all(query, values)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/databases/core.py", line 248, in __aexit__
web_1      |     await self._connection.release()
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/databases/backends/postgres.py", line 168, in release
web_1      |     self._connection = await self._database._pool.release(self._connection)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 666, in release
web_1      |     return await asyncio.shield(ch.release(timeout))
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 218, in release
web_1      |     raise ex
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 208, in release
web_1      |     await self._con.reset(timeout=budget)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 1311, in reset
web_1      |     await self.execute(reset_query, timeout=timeout)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 297, in execute
web_1      |     return await self._protocol.query(query, timeout)
web_1      |   File "asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx", line 321, in query
web_1      |   File "asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx", line 684, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.BaseProtocol._check_state
web_1      | asyncpg.exceptions._base.InterfaceError: cannot perform operation: another operation is in progress
```

How can I run the call to the data base synchronously?

---

**UPDATE DECEMBER 28, 2021**

Changing to below code as suggested by @AndreaTedeschi

```
async def get_user_by_email(email: str) -> Optional[User]:
    return await User.objects.get_or_none(email=email) 

def authenticate(email: str, password: str) -> Optional[User]:
    
    user = get_user_by_email(email=email)
    asyncio.run(user)

    if not user:
        return None
    if not verify_password(password, user.hashed_password):
        return None
    return user
```

I get an error about not attaching to the right loop. Full stack trace:

```
web_1      | Future exception was never retrieved
web_1      | future: <Future finished exception=ConnectionDoesNotExistError('connection was closed in the middle of operation')>
web_1      | asyncpg.exceptions.ConnectionDoesNotExistError: connection was closed in the middle of operation
web_1      | INFO:     172.27.0.3:42414 - "POST /auth/login HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
web_1      | ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
web_1      | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 396, in run_asgi
web_1      |     result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__
web_1      |     return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 199, in __call__
web_1      |     await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 111, in __call__
web_1      |     await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
web_1      |     raise exc from None
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
web_1      |     await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
web_1      |     raise exc from None
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
web_1      |     await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 566, in __call__
web_1      |     await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 227, in handle
web_1      |     await self.app(scope, receive, send)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 41, in app
web_1      |     response = await func(request)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 201, in app
web_1      |     raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 150, in run_endpoint_function
web_1      |     return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/concurrency.py", line 34, in run_in_threadpool
web_1      |     return await loop.run_in_executor(None, func, *args)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
web_1      |     result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
web_1      |   File "/app/./app/api/routes/auth.py", line 19, in login
web_1      |     user = authenticate(email=form_data.username, password=form_data.password)
web_1      |   File "/app/./app/core/auth.py", line 36, in authenticate
web_1      |     asyncio.run(user, debug=True)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
web_1      |     return loop.run_until_complete(main)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
web_1      |     return future.result()
web_1      |   File "/app/./app/core/auth.py", line 20, in get_user_by_email
web_1      |     return await User.objects.get_or_none(email=email) #User.objects.filter(email=email).first()
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ormar/queryset/queryset.py", line 912, in get_or_none
web_1      |     return await self.get(*args, **kwargs)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ormar/queryset/queryset.py", line 933, in get
web_1      |     return await self.filter(*args, **kwargs).get()
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ormar/queryset/queryset.py", line 953, in get
web_1      |     rows = await self.database.fetch_all(expr)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/databases/core.py", line 148, in fetch_all
web_1      |     return await connection.fetch_all(query, values)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/databases/core.py", line 264, in __aexit__
web_1      |     await self._connection.release()
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/databases/backends/postgres.py", line 168, in release
web_1      |     self._connection = await self._database._pool.release(self._connection)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 867, in release
web_1      |     return await asyncio.shield(ch.release(timeout))
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 224, in release
web_1      |     raise ex
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 214, in release
web_1      |     await self._con.reset(timeout=budget)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 1367, in reset
web_1      |     await self.execute(reset_query, timeout=timeout)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 318, in execute
web_1      |     return await self._protocol.query(query, timeout)
web_1      |   File "asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx", line 338, in query
web_1      | RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-34' coro=<PoolConnectionHolder.release() running at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py:214> cb=[shield.<locals>._inner_done_callback() at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py:885] created at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py:878> got Future <Future pending cb=[Protocol._on_waiter_completed()]> attached to a different loop
```

So some progress, but still not quite there. How would I resolve this?

Clearly I'm not an expert on async python so I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

The orm you are using is async. So methods to query the database are coroutine functions and have to be awaited.

You can not use an await espression in a normal function. You need to use the prefix `async` in order to make it a coroutine function:

```
async def get_by_username(username: str) -> Optional[User]:
    return await User.objects.get_or_none(username=username)

async def authenticate(username: str, password: str) -> Optional[User]:
    user = await get_by_username(username)
    if not user:
        return None
    # do stuff about password verificazione
    return username
```

Comment: thanks @Andrea. Unfortunately that does solve the immediate issue but led to a new issue about `asyncio.run` not being in the right loop.

Comment: You should not use asyncio.run

Comment: Make the `authenticate` method async and just await on `get_user_by_email`

Comment: Thanks @Andrea, this works! I appreciate the help